# Diophantine Equation: $xy+ax+by+c=0$

Tags: diophantine-equations

How to find integer solutions $x,y$ of $xy+ax+by+c=0$ for given $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Is there somewhere a treatise on this kind of equations?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo there?  Otherwise one could factor x from a couple of terms in the equation.

Comment: Oh,yes, thank you, it should read xy+ax+by+c=0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Remark:** We will assume that the equation is $xy+ax+by+c=0$. If it really is $xy+(a+b)x+c=0$, then it can be done in the same way as the problem below, but simpler. The equation then becomes $x(y+a+b)=-c$, and we are looking for factors of $-c$.

**Hint:** Rewrite as $(x+b)(y+a)=ab-c$.

We can find the solutions in a straightforward way once we find all divisors of $ab-c$. This includes negative divisors.

Comment: I have a related [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110818/diophantine-equation-with-division), can you please look at it?

Answer (score 1):

(I'm guessing that what was intended was $xy+ax+by+c=0$.)

\begin{align}
u & = x+y \\
v & = x-y \\[8pt]
\text{so that }x & = \frac{u+v}{2} \\[8pt]
y & = \frac{u-v}{2}
\end{align}

Then $xy = \dfrac{u^2-v^2}{4}$.  So
$$
xy + ax + by + c =0
$$
becomes
$$
\frac{u^2-v^2}{4} + a\frac{u+v}{2} + b \frac{u-v}{2} + c =0,
$$
and then multiplying both sides by $4$, we get
$$
u^2 - v^2 + 2(a+b)u + 2(a-b)v + c = 0.
$$
Then one can complete the square, getting
$$
(u+a+b)^2 - (v-a+b)^2 = (a+b)^2+(a-b)^2 - c = 2a^2+2b^2-c.
$$

Comment: That's what I was looking for. And $x^2-y^2=c$ would be a Pell's equation, that could not be easily solved, could it?

Comment: That's not Pells, since $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$ and can then check via divisors of $c$.

Comment: Right, thanks! That's where I started - I was hoping to factor $N = a^2+r = (a-x)(a+y)$