# Diophantine equation with division

Tags: diophantine-equations

How can I find all the cases where y is positive **integer** in the next equation:

$$\frac{ax + b}{c-x} = y$$

- $a,b,c,x$ are not negative integers
- $a,b,x < c$
- $ax + b = 0$ is a trivial solution

Comment: A good place to begin is to show us what you've already tried!

Comment: @daOnlyBG this equation is part of a bigger project that I am working on, this is the most encapsulated version of my problem that I can ask. I really have no idea how to address this issue. I been googeling a lot, and I found that "Diophantine equation" could be relevant, but I don't see how can I use it. So if all what you have its an idea, that works too.

Comment: That's fair, although I do have one question: if $AX+B=0$, how are $A,B,C,$ and $X$ positive integers?

Comment: @daOnlyBG sorry I meant not negative.

Comment: @AndréNicolas rewriting $xy+ax-cy=-b$ will give: $(x-c)(y+a)=-b-ac$. May be I did not mention this in the question, but I know what $A,B,C$ are. I only need to find such $X$ that will give me integer $Y$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Also this question is not supposed to be easy. Solving it will allow me to solve the integer factorization problem, this is part of my algorithm that I am building for it.

Comment: If the intent is to build a factorization algorithm, then what I wrote is useless to you since it uses factorization.

Comment: @AndréNicolas It only useless if it's as hard as the original factorization, and I think it is not. So may be, just may be, it could be the right direction, so what ever you got there: Bring it on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance with the usual convention, we avoid caps, which make equations harder to solve.

We are looking for positive integer solutions $(x,y)$ of 
$$\frac{ax+b}{c-x}=y,$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$ are non-negative and $x\lt c$.

Equivalently, we want, together with the bound on $x$, $ax+b=cy-xy$, that is, $xy+ax-cy=-b$, that is, $(x-c)(y+a)=-ac-b$, which looks better if written as
$$(c-x)(y+a)=ac+b.$$
To find all solutions, we factor $ac+b$ as $ac+b=uv$, where $1\le u\le c-1$ and $v\gt a$.

Finding non-trivial such factors (if there are any) may be computationally very difficult if $ac+b$ is large.

Comment: Thanks. I went back to my usual way of looking at things, fewer opportunities for algebra mistakes.

Comment: lols this is where I started. ac + b will be my original number that I want to factor. I thought that the way that I wrote it, will brings me close for solving it.

Comment: It looks then as if the basic problem has been *reworded*, but not fundamentally changed. Perhaps the approach will yield fruit, but the two problems are quite close to each other, and I am not optimistic.

Comment: I will keep you posted if I get new ideas. Tnx for your help

Comment: You are welcome. A notoriously difficult problem, with a very large literature.

Answer (score 0):

$Y > 0$ if $AX > B$ is the only case if you want to avoid trivial solutions

Comment: Note the constraint: $C > X$

Comment: Well noted @daOnlyBG